# IDA show xrefs in .pdata and nothing else

Tags: ida, windows, arm, arm64, uefi

I'm debugging the Windows ARM64 version's EFI (`bootaa64.efi`).

Using QEMU and GDB I was able to find that `bootaa64.efi` was stuck in one of the two functions `BlKernelSp0SystemErrorHandler` and `BlKernelExceptionHandler`. The image below is two functions when I load `bootaa64.efi` to IDA.

[image: ida]

I'm not really good at ARM64 assembly but I recognized these functions are just forever loops.

The code stuck in that loop means *somehow* the function is called. But IDA just show two xref, one is the function call itself (loop) and the other is `.pdata` xref:

I want to know what called these functions. Thanks!

[image: .pdata]

Comment: Found [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-pdata-section) about `.pdata` section. It is exception handling section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions look like exception handlers and are probably “called” by the processor when an exception or a fault happens. You need to inspect system registers to determine the cause of the exception and where it happened. See the ARM manuals for more information.

Comment: Can you provide me a link / hint for this? Thanks!

Comment: @raspiduino maybe check [ARM® Cortex™-A Series Programmer's Guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024)

Comment: Found it: the register [`ELR_EL1`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-06/AArch64-Registers/ELR-EL1--Exception-Link-Register--EL1-) hold the address to return from exception. It was true in this case, when I replace the forever loop with `ERET` (see my answer below) it return to the exact same address!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's true or not, but I patched the `B BlKernelSp0SystemErrorHandler` and `B BlKernelExceptionHandler` with `ERET` (aka exception return), and the EFI file jumps back and stop at the place of a `BRK` instruction (as a result of branching because a compare went wrong), which seems true for me since my KVM module didn't correctly implement that stubs yet.

Hope this helps for somebody.